# How to calculate the derivative of the integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The function is: $$f(x)=\int_{-1}^{x}\sin(xt)e^{-t^2}dt$$ and I need to compute the derivative $f'(0)$.
I've got $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{e}-1)$ as the answer, but I have no idea how to start. I tried finding the derivative with the fundamental theorem of Calculus, but I don't know how to treat $xt$.

Comment: Cf. Leibniz integral rule : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can apply the [Leibniz rule for integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) which states that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}g(x,t)dt \right)=g(x,b(x))b'(x)-g(x,a(x))a'(x)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(g(x,t))dt$$
Here we let
$$g(x,t)=\sin(tx)e^{-t^2}$$
By applying the formula we can see that
\begin{align}
f'(x)&= g(x,x)+\int_{1}^{x}t\cos(tx)e^{-t^2}dt\\    
     &=\sin(x^2)e^{-x^2}+\int_{1}^{x}t\cos(tx)e^{-t^2}dt
\end{align}
evaluating $f(x)$ at $x=0$:
\begin{align}
f'(0)&=\int_{1}^{0}te^{-t^2}dt\\
&=\left.-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t^2}\right|_1^0\\
&=-\frac 12+\frac{1}{2e}\\
&=\frac 12 \left(\frac 1e-1\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Good answer (+1). Try using \sin and \cos to get the right spacing